# err Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-6, vuex, vue-router

Estoy programando un SPA con Laravel y Vue.js y tengo un problema con la protección de rutas, resulta que la API envía correctamente los datos pero el spa no los recoge correctamente lanzando un error en la consola con el mensaje `Uncaught (in promise) undefined`.

Desde el `main.js` recoge el token:

```
// axios
import axios from "./axios.js"
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken')
if (token) {
    Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
}
```

mi componente dl formulario de login realiza el envío al servidor mediante esta función que a su vez consulta la acción `auth/loginJWT`:

```
loginJWT({commit}) {
      // check if the user already has a session started
      if (!this.checkLogin()) return

      // Loading
      this.$vs.loading()

      const payload = {
        checkbox_remember_me: this.checkbox_remember_me,
        userDetails: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      }

      this.$store.dispatch('auth/loginJWT', payload)
          .then(() => { this.$vs.loading.close() })
        .catch(error => {
          this.$vs.loading.close()
          this.$vs.notify({
            title: error.title,
            text: error.text,
            iconPack: error.iconPack,
            icon: error.icon,
            color: error.color
          })
        })
    },
```

estas es la accion de loginJWT:

```
loginJWT({ commit }, payload, user) {

      return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        commit('auth_request')
        jwt.login(payload.userDetails.email, payload.userDetails.password)
          .then(response => {
              this.response = response.data
              const token = response.data.accessToken
              const user = response.data.user
            // If there's user data in response
            if(token) {
              // Navigate User to homepage
              router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

              // Set accessToken
              localStorage.setItem("accessToken", token)
              localStorage.setItem("user", user)
                Vue.prototype.$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token
              // Send Request
              commit('auth_success', token, user)
              // Update user details
              commit('UPDATE_USER_INFO', user, {root: true})

              resolve(response)
            }else {
                reject({title: response.data.title, iconPack: response.data.iconPack, icon: response.data.icon, text: response.data.text, color: response.data.color})
            }

          })
          .catch(error => {
           commit('auth_error')
           localStorage.removeItem('accessToken')
           reject(error) })
      })
    },
```

Estas son las mutaciones (mutations):

```
mutations: {
  auth_request(state){
    state.status = 'loading'
  },
  auth_success(state, token, user){
    state.status = 'success'
    state.token = token
    state.user = user
  },
  auth_error(state){
    state.status = 'error'
  },
  logout(state){
    state.status = ''
    state.token = ''
  },
},
```

y por último estos son los recolectores (getters):

```
export default {
        isLoggedIn: state => !!state.token,
        authStatus: state => state.status,
}
```

Al final solo agregué el archivo store al `router.js`, que hace referencia a los demás archivos:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    getters,
    mutations,
    state: {
        status: '',
        token: localStorage.getItem('accessToken') || '',
        user : {}
    },
    actions,
    modules: {
        auth: moduleAuth,
    },
    strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
})
```

Tambien agregue el beforeEach, que si no me equivoco es el que esta provocando el problema pero no entiendo en donde si todo esta correcto:

```
router.afterEach(() => {
  // Remove initial loading
  const appLoading = document.getElementById('loading-bg')
    if (appLoading) {
        appLoading.style.display = "ratio";
    }
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {

    if(to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
        if (store.getters.isLoggedIn) {
            next()
            return
        }
        next('/pages/login')
    } else {
        next()
    }

});
```

valide con postman y la consola y la api si esta enviando los datos:

```
{
    "title": "Exito",
    "text": "Bienvenido",
    "iconPack": "feather",
    "icon": "icon-check",
    "color": "success",
    "accessToken": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwOlwvXC9teWFwcC50ZXN0XC9hcGlcL2F1dGhcL2xvZ2luIiwiaWF0IjoxNTgzNjMxNzcyLCJleHAiOjE1ODM2MzUzNzIsIm5iZiI6MTU4MzYzMTc3MiwianRpIjoiZUpoNEZRNWJYMDUxUjRVbiIsInN1YiI6MSwicHJ2IjoiODdlMGFmMWVmOWZkMTU4MTJmZGVjOTcxNTNhMTRlMGIwNDc1NDZhYSJ9.LN8pqv1s2fcyQwxlKzVPpf0IlOra70LcyGEz2JQO5Ik",
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Italia Maria",
        "email": "example@admin.com",
        "email_verified_at": null,
        "created_at": "2020-03-05 05:42:32",
        "updated_at": "2020-03-05 05:42:32"
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué fichero y en qué linea te da ese error?

Comment: has probado ejecutar el router.push en el then de tu metodo loginJWT en ves de hacerlo en el then de tu jwt.login?

Answer (score 1):

Los actions de VUEX no pueden recibir más de 2 argumentos tradicionales, para enviar más debes usar los destructurados,  por ejemplo, esta linea que tienes

```
loginJWT({ commit }, payload, user)
```

Deberia ser de esta manera:

```
loginJWT({ commit }, { payload, user } )
```

Y lo invocarias asi:

```
this.$store.dispatch('auth/loginJWT', { payload, user } );
```

Comment: El problema no es ese, en el action solamente quiero pasar el payload, ya quite el user porque no lo estaba usando en ningun lado, el problema por lo que he estado leyendo lo esta provocando la redireccion de ruta en el action LoginJWT, especificamente esta linea: router.push(router.currentRoute.query.to || '/')

Comment: pero desconozco el motivo ya que si la quito o reemplazo por otra simplemente carga todo y no redirecciona